# Regex command to insert character into column

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a text file organized into columns that looks like this:

```
#                                                v Col 50
EE84           1484.74      1364.99      62.5      2  1  0  1 
EE85           505.23       841.63       60.       2  1  0  1 
EE86           945.95       913.39       100.      1  0  0  0 
P3             972.44       1126.12      100.      1  0  0  0 
P28            980.0        1119.0       100.      1  0  0  0 
P100           964.03       1125.93      100.      1  0  0  0 
P102           963.49       1133.71      100.      1  0  0  0 
P106           974.06       1150.73      100.      1  0  0  0 
P108           1017.36      1062.47      100.      1  0  0  0 
P109           965.31       1151.14      100.      1  0  0  0
```

composed of several hundreds lines.

I need to add a value, say `0` in column 50 for each of the lines in the file, so it will look like this:

```
#                                                v Col 50
EE84           1484.74      1364.99      62.5    0  2  1  0  1 
EE85           505.23       841.63       60.     0  2  1  0  1 
EE86           945.95       913.39       100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P3             972.44       1126.12      100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P28            980.0        1119.0       100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P100           964.03       1125.93      100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P102           963.49       1133.71      100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P106           974.06       1150.73      100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P108           1017.36      1062.47      100.    0  1  0  0  0 
P109           965.31       1151.14      100.    0  1  0  0  0
```

I could paste the file into LibreOffice Calc, add the column and then paste it back, but that messes with the columns alignment.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 as my text editor, which enables the user to apply regex commands.

Which regex command could I use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*.

```
Find What: ^[^#].{48}\K
Replace With: 0
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cU7lN5/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can search using this regex:

```
/^((?:\S+\s+){49})/gm
```

Replace with this expression:

```
"${1}0  "
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iY4jU3/1)

Comment: Great answer anubhava, thank you! I'm selecting the one by hwnd because it looks a bit simpler.